# SQL Server - Horário incorreto na função GETDATE (TimeZone)

Tags: sql-server, linux, timezone, brasil

Estou com um servidor SQL Server em execução na AWS, desde ontem a função `GETDATE()` vem retornando o horário com uma hora a mais como se estivesse no fuso horário `-02:00`. Já verifiquei no Linux que a data e hora está correta e o fuso horário está definido como `America/Sao_Paulo`.

Executando o seguinte comando `EXEC MASTER.dbo.xp_regread 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE', 'SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation', 'TimeZoneKeyName'` retorna `"E. South America Standard Time"`, que na tabela `sys.time_zone_info` está com os seguintes valores:

```
+-----------------------------+
| CURRENT_UTC_OFFSET | -02:00 |
| IS_CURRENTLY_DST   | 1      |
+-----------------------------+
```

O que posso fazer para corrigir essa diferença de horário?

Comment: se entendi bem, a hora da maquina é uma (que viu no linux) e no sql está com esse offset de -2hs, é isso?

Comment: O campo IS_CURRENTLY_DST não deveria estar com 0? Afinal não estamos mais no horário de verão.

Comment: @RicardoPontual, no Linux está como -3, porém no SQL Server mostra como -2

Comment: Não achei como alterar o valor `IS_CURRENTLY_DST` para 0

Comment: E porque não simplesmente usar tudo em UTC e na aplicação setar a zona horária local do usuário? Assim fazendo o banco funcionar em qualquer lugar do mundo e evitar conflitos com as 4 diferentes zonas horarias do Brasil (sim o Brasil tem diferentes zonas horarias)?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento No meu chrome, eu dei um `alert(new Date('11/11/2019 03:00:00'))` e apareceu `Mon Nov 11 2019 03:00:00 GMT-0200 (Horário de Verão de Brasília)`. Ou seja, o fuso horário do navegador (que seria o do usuário) não é confiável.

Comment: @VictorStafusa independente disto, nem sempre o servidor tem como saber o horário do cliente, e é EXATAMENTE isto que estou dizendo, ler (SELECT) algo do servidor e fazer o parse no "front-end" pode até dar errado se o PC estiver com problema na bateria ou a sincronização falhar por causa que algum país esqueceu de enviar a zona horaria para os responsáveis (como ocorreu com o Brasil, que deu aquele baita problema). Ou seja, inserts/updates/replaces da vida se possivel que seja feito tudo no banco sem receber nada do cliente [...]

Comment: [...] e o "parse" e ajuste no front-end do que foi recebido pode até "falhar", mas não vai falhar porque esta errado no banco, vai falhar por culpa do equipamento local. E outra coisa, esse seu formato de tempo passado no `Date` código ***está errado***, o JavaScript não é adivinho, se você usasse um formato assim `2019-11-11T11:03:00.000Z`, veja o resultado: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzFBW.png, ou seja você passou um formato "solto" que o navegador vai fazer um esforço pra adivinhar, mas no máximo que vai conseguir é presumir que é horário local mesmo.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Eu sei que há como lidar com isso no javascript e que há inúmeras formas de se especificar o timezone. Só estou dizendo que esse é um problema infelizmente muito comum e que o fuso horário do cliente também não é confiável em relação ao horário de verão.

Comment: @VictorStafusa mas ai é "problema local" e o máximo que daria para fazer para resolver é ter uma área do usuário que ele informe a "zona horária dele" para que a aplicação back-end leia do banco faça o ajuste e devolva no "download"... Se a pessoa estiver com problema local em seu equipamento não vai influenciar no lado servidor, logo o problema dela vai ser todo no equipamento dela mesma, o que provavelmente até alguns certificados ou autenticações não funcionem ... certa vez a bateria da placa de um PC pifou, marcando "2001" sempre, quase nenhum programa (que usam internet) e site abriam.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento O problema é que a versão mais recente do Chrome dá o fuso horário errado para metade do Brasil a partir do dia 03/11, e os usuários leigos vão ficar bastante perdidos. Espere ver uma chuva de perguntas sobre erros referentes a horário de verão a partir desta data.

Comment: @VictorStafusa não estou sabendo disto, se for baseado no código que você postou no primeiro comentário, como disse, ele está errado, o JS assume horário local e não compensa a diferença. Agora se puder citar o problema do Chorme com detalhes, ou algum link pode ser interessante. Todavia citei cliente-side só como exemplo o navegador, cliente-side poderia ser qualquer coisa e se o tal bug existir então logo irão corrigir, mas até aonde sei os navegadores se baseiam no horário da máquina local, eu não creio que o chrome tenha horário proprio ou que cometeriam tal gafe.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento O mesmo código funciona corretamente no Firefox. O Chrome pega o fuso horário do sistema operacional, mas a tabela de horário de verão vem de algum outro lugar. Eu estou procurando bugs reports sobre isso.

Comment: @VictorStafusa entendo, mas de qualquer forma é como eu já disse, é um problema local e não afeta o servidor, o que vai dar problema GRAVE é a pessoa insistir em gravar no horário America/Brazilia no banco e depois conflitar com uma série de problemas de fusos diferentes no brasil (temos 4 fusos como eu já expliquei) e se essa aplicação/banco for "eventualmente sincronizada" com serviços de terceiros internacionais. E é este todo o proposito do meu primeiro comentário, evitar o problema grave e "irreversível" [...]

Comment: [...] E se ainda discorda de fazer o parse do UTC recebido no front a sugestão de "solução" eu já falei neste comentário: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/417475/sql-server-hor%c3%a1rio-incorreto-na-fun%c3%a7%c3%a3o-getdate-timezone?noredirect=1#comment813610_417475

Answer (score 1):

Sergio,

Peguei o mesmo erro que você. Tive que alterar o timezone do servidor para `America/Belem` porque o SQL não está reconhecendo o de São Paulo mesmo no servidor mostrando o horário correto. Faça essa alteração e reinicie o serviço do SQL para ver se resolve.